# pandas increment counter after N index

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame which looks like this .

```
df = pd.Series(["this" , "is" "some",  "text" ,  "which",  "is",  "not",  "valid"]).to_frame(name='my_text')
```

Now I want to insert a new column "ID" which start from 1 to N (some integer) . It will increment after  K number of rows . let's K is 3 here , so index 0 to 2 will have ID =1 , 3 to 5 will have ID = 2 and last index will have ID = 3.

I this can be done in pandas way without any loops .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(["this", "is", "some", "text", "which", "is", "not", "valid"]).to_frame(name='my_text')

K = 2

df['ID'] = (df.index // K) + 1

print(df)
```

The ID column is calculated by dividing the index of each row by `K`(using integer division). This assigns the same ID value to every `K` rows (i.e. increments the ID every `K` rows).